Similarity measure for sparse, ordered, binary vectors, with more weighting to True values
I have two sparse, ordered, binary vectors. The size of the vectors is around ~100.
I am under the impression that cosine similarity is useful for sparse, ordered, binary vectors. For my purposes, it is good, BUT not exactly what I am looking for.
Say I have two sets of pairs of vectors: A =: {{0,0,0}, {0,0,0}} and B =: {{1,1,1}, {1,1,1}}. The cosine similarity between (A1, A2) and (B1, B2) are the same since both pairs are identical HOWEVER, I would like a measure that weighs more to B, because it has more observations of 1's.
I can create a rudimentary measure by summing up the amount of 1's in the vector, then multiplying this by the cosine similarity.
This unfortunately gives TOO much weighting to the amount of 1's, since some vectors are all 1's.
I was just curious if there was a more thought-out (possibly accurate) method? Something that accounts for more 1 values but has a penalty for too many?
